# How to change order of integration with changing limits (Lebesgue integral)

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Let $f \in L^1\big( (0,1)^2 \big)$. How to prove

$$ \int_{x=0}^1  \int_{t=0}^x f(t,x) \,dt \, dx=\int_{t=0}^1  \int_{x=t}^1 f(t,x) \,dx \, dt.$$

Both integrals cover the triangle bounded by the graph of the function $t(x)=x$ and the axes.

I guess Fubini should be used somewhere, but I am not sure how; Naively, this is *not* an intergal over a product.

Comment: "Naively, this is not an intergal over a product." It can be, with judicious use of indicator functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $g(t,x) = \displaystyle \left\{ \begin{array}{lc} 1 & 0 \le x \le 1 \text{ and  } 0 \le t \le x \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{array} \right.$

Then
$$\int_{x=0}^1  \int_{t=0}^x f(t,x) \,dt \, dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(t,x)g(t,x) \, dt \, dx.$$

Now apply Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Very nice! +1 for elegance.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^x f(t,x) \,dt \right) dx=\int_0^1 \left( \int_t^1 f(t,x) \,dx \right) dt
$$

Both of these are equal to
$$
\iint\limits_{\{\,(t,x)\,:\, 0 \, \le \, t\, \le\,x\,\le\,  1\,\}} f(t,x) \, d(t,x)
$$
Look at the subscript:
$$
0 \le t\le x\le 1.
$$
One can say $x$ goes from $0$ to $1,$ and then for each fixed value of $x,$ $t$ goes from $0$ to $x.$

Or one can say $t$ goes from $0$ to $1,$ and then for each fixed value of $t,$ $x$ goes from $t$ to $1.$

**Technical note:** Fubini's theorem says the three integrals shown above are equal **if**
$$
\iint\limits_{\{\,(t,x)\,:\, 0 \, \le \, t\, \le\,x\,\le\,  1\,\}} |f(t,x)| \, d(t,x) < +\infty.
$$
Note the absolute value.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is a rigorous proof. Indeed, both integrals cover the same triangle, but formally you need to use some version of Fubini, in order to justify the order change  of the integrals. (See Umberto P.'s answer).